# Run a method after a dialog is dismissed - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a fragment that creates a dialogFragment with no buttons. I want the fragment to run a method after the dialog has been dismissed by either the back button or by clicking outside of the dialog. I have tried looking for an answer, but all I have found is the possibility of setting up positive/negative/neutral buttons. I wouldn't want buttons if possible. How could this be accomplished?

Note: I have tried onResume(), but that doesn't get called after the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override the `onDismiss` method in the DialogFragment, that gets called when the dialog gets dismissed

Comment: Override the `onDismiss` in the dialogFragment? If that's the case, I don't believe I can do that, because I use the dialogFragment in 4 places, but only want it to run this method in 1 place.

Comment: when you create the dialog in that specific place send in a boolean in the bundle indicating this time you want that piece to run. then in the on dismiss an if statement dictates if it runs or not based on the bundle value you sent

Comment: With `fragment.setArguments()`?

Comment: yes, then use `getArguments` in your dialogfragment with the default value of false so that in every other case besides this special case it will be false

Answer (score 3):

the method setOnDismissListener and setOnCancelListener is not avaliable?

I think you can do this:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

or:

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                //YOUR CODE
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hmm.. those methods don't seem to exist.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html
Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself. To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and onDismiss(DialogInterface).

Comment: it's like @tyczj said. You have to overide these methods